# Compose Extension: One command displayed twice in MS Teams compose box

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.5",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "BOT-ID",
  "packageName": "com.microsoft.teams.appName",
  "developer": {
    "name": "dev",
    "websiteUrl": "https://secure.dev.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://secure.dev.com/privacy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://secure.dev.com/termsofuse"
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "icon-color.png",
    "outline": "icon-outline.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "My Bot",
    "full": "My Helpdesk Bot"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "My Bot App",
    "full": "My bot to create, update tickets and get helpdesk notifications"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "BOT-ID",
      "scopes": ["team"],
      "supportsFiles": false,
      "isNotificationOnly": false,
      "commandLists": []
    }
  ],
  "composeExtensions": [
    {
      "botId": "BOT-ID",
      "commands": [
        {
          "id": "createTicket",
          "type": "action",
          "description": "Command to run action to create a Ticket from Compose Box",
          "title": "Create Ticket",
          "context": ["message", "compose"],
          "fetchTask": true,
          "initialRun": true
        },
        {
          "id": "addComment",
          "type": "action",
          "description": "Add comment on My app",
          "title": "Add Comment",
          "context": ["message"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "token.botframework.com",
    "*.ngrok.io"
  ]
}
```

I have installed only one instance of my MS Teams app in a teams channel but it displays commands twice.

I have added bot and message extensions both in my app and when I set bot scope to 'personal' only then it shows me single command but when I set bot's scope to 'teams' then it display commands twice.

Comment: Can you please share your manifest file via hiding the PII data?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft I've added it to my question. Please have a look.